# How to show the participation percentage in each department?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employees Table: EmployeeID, Name, OrgCode
Departments Table: OrgCode, DepatName
CompleteSurvey Table: ID, ParticipantID
```

And I need to develop a table that shows the total number of employees in each department, and the total number of participants who completed the survey in each department, too. Then, I want to show the percentage of participation in each department which is mainly equal to the total number of participants / total number of employees.

I came up with the following two queries but I have to come up with one query that shows the above requirement, **so how to do that?**

---

Total number of employees in each department:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Employees.EmployeeID) AS [Total Number of Employees], 
       dbo.Departments.DepartmentName
FROM dbo.Departments 
INNER JOIN dbo.Employees ON dbo.Departments.OrgCode = dbo.Employees.OrgCode
GROUP BY dbo.Departments.DepartmentName
```

---

Total number of participants in each department:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Employees.EmployeeID) AS [Total Number of Employees], 
 dbo.Departments.DepartmentName
 FROM dbo.Departments 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Employees ON dbo.Departments.OrgCode = dbo.Employees.OrgCode 
 INNER JOIN dbo.CompleteSurvey ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeID = dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID
 GROUP BY dbo.Departments.DepartmentName
```

The problem with the second query that shows the participants, it doesn't show all the departments even if they have no participants, it should show zeros.

**UPDATE:**

Basically, what I want is to have one query that shows the total number of employees in each department and the total number of participants who completed the survey in each department, and show the percentage of participation.

Comment: Instead of using inner joins you must use left outer joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly that CompleteSurvey is filled with EmployeeID when employe submits a survey, this query will retrieve the info you need. You can check [live test @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6aa97/4).

```
select Departments.DepatName, 
       count (Employees.EmployeeID) Employees, 
       count (CompleteSurvey.ID) Finished,
       cast (count (CompleteSurvey.ID) as float) / count (Employees.EmployeeID)
            PercentageFinished
  from Departments
 inner join Employees 
    on Departments.OrgCode = Employees.OrgCode
  left join CompleteSurvey 
    on Employees.EmployeeID = CompleteSurvey.ParticipantID
 group by Departments.DepatName
```

If you need all the departments, use this query:

```
select Departments.DepatName, 
       count (Employees.EmployeeID) Employees, 
       count (CompleteSurvey.ID) Finished,
       case when count (Employees.EmployeeID) <> 0
            then cast (count (CompleteSurvey.ID) as float) 
                     / count (Employees.EmployeeID)
            else 0
        end PercentageFinished
  from Departments
  left join Employees 
    on Departments.OrgCode = Employees.OrgCode
  left join CompleteSurvey 
    on Employees.EmployeeID = CompleteSurvey.ParticipantID
 group by Departments.DepatName
```

New [test @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f60af/2).

Comment: I would add  "having count(employees.employeeID) >0" to prevent divide by zero errors

Comment: @Satish inner join between Departments and Employees takes care of that. But yes, if OP wants to see departments having no employees, this would be mandatory.

Comment: Yeah, I wan to see all the departments even those which have no employees, so how to modify the query? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @user1396717 Please check my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking something like this (using tables variables)

```
DECLARE @Employees Table(EmployeeID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), OrgCode VARCHAR(50) )  
DECLARE @Departments Table( OrgCode INT, DepartmentName  VARCHAR(50)     )
DECLARE @CompleteSurvey Table( ID INT, RespondantID INT) 

INSERT INTO  @Employees VALUES(12,'Emp 12', 1000),(13,'Emp 13', 1000),(112,'Emp 112', 2000),    (113,'Emp 114', 2000)
INSERT INTO @Departments VALUES(1000, 'dept 1000'),(2000, 'dept 2000')
,(3000, 'no employee dept 3000')
INSERT INTO @CompleteSurvey VALUES (901,12), (901,112),(902,13), (902,112)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  EmployeeID) AS [Total Number of Employees],  D.DepartmentName FROM     @Departments D 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Employees E
ON  D.OrgCode =  E.OrgCode GROUP BY  D.DepartmentName

SELECT D.DepartmentName,COUNT(DISTINCT E.EmployeeID) AS [Total Number of Employees], 
COUNT(DISTINCT S.RespondantID )AS completed_survey ,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT E.EmployeeID)>0 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT S.RespondantID )/
CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT E.EmployeeID)AS FLOAT)*100 ELSE 0 END AS particPerc
FROM @Departments D LEFT OUTER JOIN @Employees E ON D.OrgCode = E.OrgCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @CompleteSurvey S ON E.EmployeeID =S.RespondantID GROUP BY D.DepartmentName
```

which outputs:

```
 Total Number of Employees  DepartmentName
  2                       dept 1000
  2                       dept 2000
  0                       no employee dept 3000
```

and finally what I think you're asking for

```
DepartmentName  Total Number of Employees   completed_survey   particPerc
dept 1000                  2                             2          100
dept 2000                  2                             1           50
no employee dept 3000        0                           0            0
```

Comment: Yeah, your answer is definitely correct and I like it. Thanks for your help, too.