# How to show the total number of employees and participants, and participation percentage in all departments?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employees Table: EmployeeID, Name, OrgCode
Departments Table: OrgCode, DepartName
CompleteSurvey Table: ID, ParticipantID
```

And I need to develop one query that will display a table that shows the total number of employees in all departments and the total number of participants who completed the survey in all departments.

I could be able to find the total number of employees in all department by the following query:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Employees.EmployeeID) AS [Total Number of Employees]
FROM         dbo.Departments INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Employees ON dbo.Departments.OrgCode = dbo.Employees.OrgCode CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.CompleteSurvey
```

Then, I could be able to find the total number of participants in all department by the following query:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CompleteSurvey.ID) AS [Total Number of Participants]
FROM         dbo.Departments INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Employees ON dbo.Departments.OrgCode = dbo.Employees.OrgCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.CompleteSurvey ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeID = dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID
```

But I should have a one query only.

For example, if Department A has 100 employee and the number of participants is 50 out of 100
and Department B has 80 employee and the number of participants is 30

The query should show the following:

**the total number of employees in all departments = 180**

**the total number of participants in all departments = 80**

**the percent completion in all of them = 80/180 = 44%**

**So how to do that?**

Comment: [Was there something wrong with previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605262/how-to-show-the-participation-percentage-in-each-department/10605689#10605689)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to involve the `Department` table in these calculations:

```
SELECT
  TotalEmployees          = COUNT(*),
  TotalParticipants       = COUNT(s.ParticipantID),
  ParticipationPercentage = COUNT(s.ParticipantID) * 100.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Employee e
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ParticipantID FROM dbo.CompleteSurvey) s
    ON e.EmployeeID = s.ParticipantID
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SQL Server, I hope an Oracle solution could help too:

```
select e.employees, c.respondents, (c.respondents / e.employees) * 100 percentage
  from (select count(*) employees from employees) e,
       (select count(*) respondents from complete_survey) c
```

Comment: you count responses, not participants (the same person can answer multiple surveys), but +1 anyway, it's easy to correct. MS SQL is different only in case sensitivity in this case (=> `from Employees`, `from CompleteSurvey`)